# Delete record if it doesn't have child record related to it in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a shop table and item table guys. So I want to delete shop from shop table. Shop should be deleted if it doesn't have any item and can't delete if it has item. The code written here is not deleting shop whether there is an item or not. This is my controller:

```
public function deleteShop()
    {
        if ( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in() OR ! $this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {    
            $id = 0;        
            $shop_id = $_GET['shop_id']; 
            $results = $this->shop_model->getShopIdFromItem($shop_id);


            if($results) {
                    foreach ($results as $key) {
                        $id = $key->shop_id;
                    }
                    if($id == $shop_id) {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'There is an item with this Shop. You cannot delete this!');
                        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/shop','refresh');
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = true;
                    if($result) {
                        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/shop', 'refresh');
                    } else {
                        echo "Something went wrong!";
                    }
                }
        }
```

This is my model:

```
function getShopIdFromItem($shop_id) {
        $this->db->select('category_id');
        $this->db->from('item');
        $this->db->where('shop_id', $shop_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function delete($shop_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('shop_id', $shop_id);
        $this->db->delete('shop'); 
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

Comment: Where you are calling `delete` function?

Comment: Against one `shop_id` is there multiple record in `item` table?

Comment: You're not calling the `delete()` method at all so that's likely why. I am guessing where you assign `$result` to true you mean to actually call `delete()`

Comment: Yes Danish Ali, there are many item record related to one shop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete($shop_id)
{
$this->db->from('item');
$this->db->where('shop_id', $shop_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() == 0) {
    $this->db->where('shop_id', $shop_id);
    $this->db->delete('shop'); 
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

change your delete method ...  it will only delete if it dose not have any item available ..

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but op wants to delete the shop only if there are no items in it - so you should correct your line  `if($query->num_rows() > 0)` to `if($query->num_rows() == 0)`.